# Angular1.5 / Pure Javascript : To return the variables on onmouseup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

- I've a  mouseUpEvent listener that runs getSelectionText function.
- getSelectionText captures the selected range with window.getSelection and stores in a var.

I would like replace current selected range text, wrap the HTML with HTML tags and re-render.

HTML

```
   <div ng-mouseup="mouseUpEvent()">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus aliquam sodales ipsum quis tincidunt. In scelerisque lorem a metus volutpat volutpat. 
      </div>
```

JS

```
//Get Selected Content
$scope.mouseUpEvent = function() {
     // Get the user selected content and store in a var
     $scope.selectedText =  $scope.getSelectionText();

    //need a function to return the selected content but wrapped with <b></b>


};  

//Get selection range    
$scope.getSelectionText = function(){
  var userSelectedText = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
      userSelectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
     $scope.myselectText = window.getSelection().toString();

       $scope.myselectText.replace ($scope.myselectText, 'yellow');

  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      userSelectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;

  }


  return userSelectedText;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a super simple solution to your question (using pure vanilla js)

You can add Event Listeners to objects in two ways.

By adding the listener to the object in HTML

```
<div id="myButton" onMouseUp="doSomething()"></div>
```

or from JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    //Do something when the mouse Up event happens.
});
```

If you would like JavaScript to add the eventListeners automatically when the page loads then you could use this

```
 window.onload = function(){

     document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("mouseup", function(){ DO SOMETHING CODE HERE; });

 };
```

**SOLVING YOUR EXAMPLE**

HTML

```
<div id="SampleText" onMouseUp="captureText()">Please select this text</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function captureText() {
 var text = "";

 if (window.getSelection) {
   text = window.getSelection().toString();
 } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== "Control") {
   text = document.selection.createRange().text;
 }

 return text;
 //or pass text to a function for it to be used useText(text);
}//End function
```

> UPDATE:

If you would like to capture selected text from the entire page then you will need to wrap the entire page in a wrapper and add the evenListener to the wrapper.

```
<div id="PageWrapper" onMouseUp="captureText()">
  //All Page content goes here
</div><!-- End PageWrapper -->
```

Comment: How would you return a different content to the selected content ?

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs i have made a few edits to my original post to fix some things so i am not sure which version you are responding to.
 
But based on how this is set up... You simply add an EventListener that calls the captureText() function (onMouseUp) to any element you want to capture selected text from. When the mouseUp event fires, what ever text is currently selected will be captured and returned/passed to another function. The value of the text variable is updated everytime a new selection is made (and the MouseUp event is fired).

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs ok i just added one last update that will assist you in capturing selected text from anywhere on the page.

Comment: I was more asking about How to replace the selected content for example with <b> elements wrapped around it?
I trying to select text and replace with <b>%selectedText%</b>

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs oh... well that was not mentioned in your question. Then you will have to know what element on the page the selection is being made from.. then you will have to capture the entire innerHTML of the element... then run a string replace on the entire innerHTML text (replacing the selected text with <b>+SelectedText+</b>  ...store that new text as NewText or something. Then replace the entire innerHTML of the element that contains the selected text.

Comment: I've add changes to my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular you have **ng-mouseup**
Here is an example on how you do in angular

**HTML**

```
<div ng-mouseup="getSelectedText()">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer hendrerit lacus gravida augue mattis, quis auctor ex pulvinar.

</div>

<div ng-bind="showSelections"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function myCtrl($scope){
   $scope.getSelectedText = function(){
      $scope.showSelection = $scope.getSelectionText();
   };
   $scope.getSelectionText = function() {
      var selectedText = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
          selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
          selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
      }
      return selectedText;
   };
}
```